# Update a provisioning profile using App Store Connect API. How?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I would like to re-generate a set of provisioning profiles using [App Store Connect API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi).
There are methods for creating new profiles, deleting existing, but I see no method to update profiles.

Is anyone aware of such a method?

The need to regenerating is that there is a big number of these profiles and I need to update the profiles preserving all the information but the certificate, which is going to expire soon.
It is possible to regenerate manually in the console, but I would prefer a pretty small script for this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi bro, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The api doesn't support editing or updating a provisioning profile as far as I am aware.

Instead it is possible to get the details from the old provisioning profile then make a new provisioning profile with those details. Then delete the old profile.

You'd need to give it a new name, I'd personally either use a number or an alternating pattern at the end of the provisioning profile name to ensure Apple unique name constraint is upheld.